# Error Encountered: An unexpected error occurred

Tags: google-apps-script

Suddenly the scripts I was working on, are all stating this error when I use a click handler: `Error Encountered: An unexpected error occurred`

**For example :**

```
var clickHandlerColapse = app.createServerClickHandler("respondColapse");
upButton.addClickHandler(clickHandlerColapse);<br>
clickHandlerColapse.addCallbackElement(verPanel);
```

**Calling the function:**

```
function respondColapse(e) {
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.getElementById('abpanel').setVisible(false);
    return app.close();
}
```

Any ideas what could cause this or why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this simple code :

```
function buttontest() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight('50').setWidth('150');
  app.setTitle("test this button");
  var panel = app.createFlowPanel()
  var quit = app.createButton('quit');
  app.add(panel.add(quit));

  var QHandler = app.createServerHandler("quit");
  quit.addClickHandler(QHandler);

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
//
function quit(){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close()
  return app;
  }
```

On Chrome and safari (mac) It causes an error 'An unexpected error occurred'

Comment: Damn it! Now it happens with me every time as well, in all my scripts :-(

Comment: 8:45 PM CEST This is fixed now .

Answer (score 0):

This error is simple. There's no widget on your UI with the id "abpanel".

You could have typed it wrong or is confusing the widget "name" with its "id", which are different things.

Anyway, why are you doing any work on this handler at all if you're just closing the UI in the end? `return app.close();` will just finish it. If that's not intentional, replace this line with `return app;`

Comment: It was in the close(); in the functions! Thanks Henrique!  btw we have the challenge coming up at the end of june.

Comment: Is your issue completely solved ? It happend to you just afew hours ago and now there seem to be an [issue related to this](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1394)

Comment: I doubt it is related serge, as he don't call and `add` on the handler. At least not in the code shown.

Comment: Hi Henrique, I tested also on a very simple UI and get the error too...   I'll write the code in a new answer as comments are inappropriate.